# Grouping and summing items in a table using SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report, and I'm trying to sum up rows conditionally. I have:

11/15/2010 12:14:43 AM | Current Rate | Current Speed | Amount used in that minute (Speed*Rate/60) 
etc etc etc

I am trying to add all the rows that happened in an hour, so that my report will show:

11/15/2010 | 12 AM - 1 AM | Amount used for that hour (say, 7 gallons)

I cannot find anywhere how to conditionally sum up a row per hour, or how to get my report to say the above.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're trying to do this in the report, vs the SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, in the report. I was hoping to use the Expression feature to do this.

Comment: I agree with OMG Ponies, this would be simpler to do in SQL and then present the result to the report (probably faster too). You say you were "...hoping to use the Expression feature..." can you explain why you prefer that method?

Comment: Just because I'm more comfortable with it :) If SQL can do it better, than I'm all ears on how to do so!

Comment: @Sarah: See the answer I posted for the solution using SQL in stead of Expressions in reports.

Comment: Despite it being possible to do it in the SQL, it's still a good question. Often due to time, bureaucracy etc it's easier to put changes in the report rather than in SQL, esp if you don't own the proc or the proc is used by a host of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following table for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `entry_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_used` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

With some test data:

```
entry_date           amount_used
2010-11-01 10:00:00, 3
2010-11-01 10:30:00, 1
2010-11-01 11:00:00, 6
```

Use this query to get the date, hour range and total amount used:

```
SELECT DATE(entry_date) AS entry_date, 
    CONCAT_WS('-',CONVERT(MIN(HOUR(entry_date)), char(2)), CONVERT(MAX(HOUR(entry_date)),CHAR(2))) hours,
    SUM(amount_used) amount_used
FROM (
    SELECT entry_date, SUM(amount_used) AS amount_used 
    FROM log
    GROUP BY DATE(entry_date), HOUR(entry_date)
    ) T;
```

All the CONCAT/CONVERT stuff is just to get the range of hours in that particular day, as a string. This is the result:

```
entry_date  hours  amount_used
2010-11-01, 10-11, 10
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tony, this was a great help to me!

Comment: I made a new dataset and pasted the query, changing the names to the ones in my db. However, when I try to execute the query I get the 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? I only have MYSQL available at the moment. To change to T-SQL replace the HOUR function with DATEPART(HOUR, entry_date). To get only the DATE from a DATETIME in T-SQL you have to do a rather nasty hack using something like this: CAST(FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)

Comment: And you will have to change all the CONCAT_WS stuff to just use '+', have a read on the web about string concatenation and casting in T-SQL as I can't remember the best way at the moment :)

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2008. Thanks again, I did not realize this was going to be quite so complicated and I'm still learning the language. I'll try that tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: It became more complex because of deriving the range of hours with results in each day. If you only wanted to report the total amount used for each day you only need the inner SELECT and can do away with all the string conversion and concatenation.

Comment: @Sarah: I realised this morning my query is not correct for the output you want. I'm rolling up all the results for a day in to one row with the MIN and MAX hours, you want the result per hour. In which case only use the inner query (although it will require some formatting)